# f(x) isn't continous, but |f(x)| is

Tags: real-analysis

I was working with this problem:

[image]

$f(x) = 1, x \in(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)\\
f(x)  = -1, x = 0 $

The absolute value would yield us the function: $|f(x)| = 1, \forall x\in(-\infty,\infty)$

Hence, it'd become continous everywhere.

Thank you for any feedback. And as a side question, is there a way to find more such functions, in an easy way?

Comment: Yea, literally just take any continuous non-zero non-negative function, and negate its value at a point where it is positive. (Your example is an example of this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, anytime you have a function whose absolute value is already continuous (whether or not it is continuous other than abs),  $g: x \in \Bbb X\mapsto g(x)$; $g(x)$ is not identically $0$, $c:|c|=1; c\not = 1$, and some proper subset $\Bbb Y$ of $\Bbb X, \Bbb Y \neq \emptyset, f(\Bbb Y)$ and $f(\Bbb X \setminus \Bbb Y)$ are not identically $0$, you can make your function $f$ have this property by defining it to be:

$f(x) = \begin{cases}
                                   g(x) & \text{if $x\in \Bbb{Y}$} \\
                                   cg(x) & \text{if $x \in \Bbb{X \setminus Y}$} \\ \end{cases}$

If you are working only in the real numbers, it will be $\Bbb X =\Bbb R $ and your $c$ will be $-1$.

Comment: What if $\mathbb X=\mathbb C$? This doesn't work without some conditions on $\mathbb X$.

Comment: @DonThousand good catch!!

Comment: @DonThousand do you mean if f($\Bbb Y$) is identically 0?

Answer (score 1):

A simple example is

$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
-1, & x < 0\\
1, & x \ge 0
\end{cases},
$$

which is not continuous at $x=0$, but $|f(x)|= 1, x \in \mathbb{R}$. More generally, just take any non negative continuous function and swap its sign in points where it is not zero.

Answer (score -2):

What about
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x & \text{if }x\in\mathbb{Q} \\ -x & \text{if }x\in\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q} \end{cases}$$
Just separe points of domain on rationals and irrationals and give them opposite aditive functions, as this way you can have a lot of functions with the properties you ask

Comment: OP already has an example of such a function. OP wants to know if there is an easy construction for many of these sorts of questions.

Comment: @RushabhMehta you clearly didn't read. I have told him a way to construct many of the sort of functions in a very, veeeryy simple way.